# Interstitial Ads Not Showing in 1st Scene

Tags: unity, c#, admob

I want to show interstitial ads in my game's 1st scene. Whenever game is opened, ads should show inside it.

When I use the Play Button ads work ok, but it's showing on the next scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class Admob : MonoBehaviour
{    
    InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public string InterstitialId;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Request Ads
        //RequestBanner();
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    public void showInterstitialAd()
    {
        //Show Ad
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = InterstitialId;
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `showInterstitialAd`?

Comment: @DMGregory i have create a game and using 2 scene one is menu scene option other one is game scene and i put this code on empty game object as well as main camera but ads not showing. log report show ad loaded but when i use play button on click method to call ads its showing on 2nd scene . but i need on my 1st scene plz help

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a lot of information about where you call this method, but based on what we can see I'd suspect your problem may be here:

```
public void showInterstitialAd()
{
    //Show Ad
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
}
```

This tries exactly once to show the ad. If the ad hasn't loaded yet (because the game just started up and it hasn't had time to process the request & download the ad in its entirety), then it gives up and never shows the ad.

You can make this more robust like this...

```
Coroutine pendingAd;

IEnumerator ShowIntersitialAdWhenReady() {
    // As long as the ad hasn't leaded, let the game keep running.
    while(interstitial.IsLoaded() == false)
        yield return null;

    // Now the ad has loaded - show it.
    interstitial.Show();

    // Clear out our "pending" state.
    pendingAd = null;
}
```

Now your show method can look like this:

```
public void ShowInterstitialAd()
{
    if (pendingAd == null)
        pendingAd = StartCoroutine(ShowInterstitialAdWhenReady());
}
```

If the ad isn't ready when you first try to show it, then we'll buffer the request and show it as soon as we can.

You can use the `pendingAd` variable to make sure you don't accidentally try to show the same ad twice, and can cancel the ad show request if you change states while it's still pending.